# Slicing Data and Aggregating a Count

Tags: python

So the overall task is as follows:
Using the provided climate_data_Dec2017.csv file, your task is to find out how many readings there were across our recorded weather stations for each wind direction on the 26th of December.

The file contains data for more than this particular day, so you will have to use a filtering statement to make sure you only include readings from the 26th.

Aggregate the number of readings in a dictionary. If there aren't any records for a particular wind direction, it should still appear in the dictionary and have the value zero.

So the actual data set includes:

```
Date,State,City,Station Code,Minimum temperature (C),Maximum temperature (C),Rainfall (mm),Evaporation (mm),Sunshine (hours),Direction of maximum wind gust,Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h),9am Temperature (C),9am relative humidity (%),3pm Temperature (C),3pm relative humidity (%)
2017-12-25,VIC,Melbourne,086338,15.1,21.4,0,8.2,10.4,S,44,17.2,57,20.7,54
2017-12-25,VIC,Bendigo,081123,11.3,26.3,0,,,ESE,46,17.2,53,25.5,25
2017-12-25,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,22.3,35.7,0,,,SE,59,29.2,53,27.7,67
2017-12-25,SA,Adelaide,023034,13.9,29.5,0,10.8,12.4,SE,43,18.6,42,27.7,17
2017-12-25,QLD,Brisbane,040913,22.5,36.2,0,11.0,10.0,WSW,61,29.5,53,32.3,53
2017-12-25,QLD,Townsville,032040,24.8,32.5,0,,,NNE,41,29.1,55,31.1,48
2017-12-25,QLD,Cairns,031011,20.3,33.3,0,,,E,41,29.2,59,32.4,45
2017-12-25,NSW,Wollongong,068228,15.9,21.3,7.6,,,SSW,48,18.5,80,19.5,70
2017-12-25,NSW,Newcastle,061055,19.8,21.6,0.6,,,S,48,20.2,83,20.9,74
2017-12-25,VIC,Ballarat,089002,8.5,21.4,0,,,SSE,54,13.3,62,21.1,40
2017-12-25,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,20.2,31.5,0,,,NNE,43,28.9,62,28.8,61
2017-12-25,NSW,Canberra,070351,13.4,23.0,0,,,ESE,39,15.0,66,21.9,47
2017-12-25,NSW,Albury,072160,14.7,29.1,0,,,SSE,37,18.7,42,26.6,32
2017-12-25,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,19.5,32.0,0,,,E,61,24.4,68,31.2,39
2017-12-25,VIC,Geelong,087184,14.1,21.6,0,,,S,41,16.7,58,19.9,53
2017-12-25,NT,Darwin,014015,24.0,27.6,20.0,6.6,0.0,NNE,46,25.4,91,27.3,81
2017-12-25,WA,Perth,009021,19.7,33.1,0,11.0,13.3,SW,39,27.8,34,31.1,29
2017-12-26,VIC,Ballarat,089002,10.8,29.1,0,,,SE,56,17.3,59,27.1,30
2017-12-26,NSW,Canberra,070351,10.8,22.4,0,,,E,39,18.3,57,21.8,48
2017-12-26,QLD,Brisbane,040913,19.0,29.7,54.8,12.4,7.5,E,26,25.2,77,28.8,56
2017-12-26,NSW,Newcastle,061055,18.5,22.5,3.8,,,SE,43,21.1,76,21.7,79
2017-12-26,SA,Adelaide,023034,18.0,33.3,0,11.4,12.7,E,43,25.7,23,28.6,28
2017-12-26,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,16.4,28.4,0,,,E,74,23.9,65,22.7,79
2017-12-26,WA,Perth,009021,15.4,27.4,0,9.0,13.2,SW,41,22.3,59,25.7,45
2017-12-26,VIC,Bendigo,081123,12.8,31.3,0,,,SE,41,20.5,50,30.3,27
2017-12-26,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,20.4,27.9,11.6,,,SSE,52,24.7,87,25.8,81
2017-12-26,VIC,Geelong,087184,12.5,26.6,0,,,SSE,31,18.9,69,23.8,50
2017-12-26,VIC,Melbourne,086338,12.5,30.5,0,8.0,12.9,SSE,37,17.4,66,27.0,43
2017-12-26,QLD,Cairns,031011,22.0,33.0,0,,,ENE,33,29.2,61,31.1,56
2017-12-26,NSW,Wollongong,068228,17.8,24.1,0,,,ENE,41,21.3,59,23.9,55
2017-12-26,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,19.9,28.6,7.4,,,ESE,33,28.4,67,27.6,68
2017-12-26,QLD,Townsville,032040,23.4,32.4,0,,,NE,37,29.9,52,30.4,50
2017-12-26,NSW,Albury,072160,14.0,30.7,0,,,NNE,31,21.6,46,29.2,26
2017-12-26,NT,Darwin,014015,24.6,31.6,8.0,4.6,1.4,NNW,56,26.7,90,30.3,72
2017-12-27,WA,Perth,009021,14.5,26.5,0,11.8,12.3,SSW,54,21.4,49,25.5,34
2017-12-27,NSW,Wollongong,068228,18.8,25.1,0,,,NE,43,21.8,77,23.3,72
2017-12-27,VIC,Geelong,087184,14.9,37.2,0,,,N,41,26.4,46,35.9,20
2017-12-27,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,21.5,28.8,1.4,,,SE,33,26.5,73,27.6,66
2017-12-27,NSW,Albury,072160,15.0,32.5,0,,,E,30,23.6,54,30.9,29
2017-12-27,VIC,Ballarat,089002,15.3,32.9,0,,,N,56,22.2,55,30.9,30
2017-12-27,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,16.7,26.9,29.4,,,E,57,20.4,80,26.1,57
2017-12-27,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,20.3,29.4,0.2,,,S,41,26.4,72,27.5,71
2017-12-27,NSW,Canberra,070351,15.8,29.1,0,,,NE,33,18.9,68,26.4,37
2017-12-27,SA,Adelaide,023034,20.6,36.0,0,8.8,3.8,WSW,48,32.9,9,28.9,34
2017-12-27,VIC,Melbourne,086338,17.3,34.5,0,11.8,10.4,NW,46,25.3,45,32.9,32
2017-12-27,VIC,Bendigo,081123,16.3,35.6,0,,,N,46,22.7,54,32.9,30
2017-12-27,QLD,Cairns,031011,22.4,32.6,0,,,NE,35,29.1,59,31.3,55
2017-12-27,QLD,Townsville,032040,23.2,32.8,0,,,NE,37,30.3,52,30.0,59
2017-12-27,QLD,Brisbane,040913,20.7,29.6,3.0,5.6,10.0,E,30,27.3,60,28.2,56
2017-12-27,NSW,Newcastle,061055,20.5,23.5,0,,,E,39,22.1,80,22.9,79
2017-12-27,NT,Darwin,014015,23.5,31.3,8.8,3.0,0.0,NW,15,28.7,77,29.5,73
2017-12-28,NSW,Newcastle,061055,19.8,24.3,0,,,E,41,22.6,76,23.6,81
2017-12-28,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,16.6,27.9,0,,,E,43,21.3,73,27.4,52
2017-12-28,SA,Adelaide,023034,21.1,25.0,0,10.2,1.0,SSE,26,22.1,82,23.8,74
2017-12-28,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,20.4,28.8,24.0,,,E,31,26.0,69,27.6,63
2017-12-28,VIC,Ballarat,089002,20.1,30.4,0,,,NW,31,25.1,42,29.3,31
2017-12-28,NSW,Wollongong,068228,19.8,25.3,0,,,NE,39,23.2,73,23.8,75
2017-12-28,NSW,Canberra,070351,12.9,32.4,0,,,NW,37,20.1,70,32.4,31
2017-12-28,VIC,Bendigo,081123,22.6,34.4,0,,,NNE,24,26.2,43,32.6,29
2017-12-28,QLD,Townsville,032040,26.9,32.6,0,,,ENE,39,30.2,57,31.0,54
2017-12-28,WA,Perth,009021,15.7,28.8,0,11.2,13.2,SSW,52,22.1,44,25.6,40
2017-12-28,VIC,Melbourne,086338,24.0,32.8,0,14.0,4.1,SSW,31,26.4,46,23.9,73
2017-12-28,QLD,Brisbane,040913,20.6,29.4,0.6,7.8,12.5,ESE,24,27.5,60,28.8,57
2017-12-28,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,20.7,28.9,0,,,SSE,35,26.5,75,28.1,64
2017-12-28,NSW,Albury,072160,17.4,32.8,0,,,ENE,35,22.3,63,31.9,39
2017-12-28,VIC,Geelong,087184,22.9,28.0,0,,,S,39,25.7,54,20.7,85
2017-12-28,NT,Darwin,014015,25.6,34.5,1.0,0.8,9.8,WNW,31,31.0,72,33.1,62
2017-12-28,QLD,Cairns,031011,22.6,34.2,0,,,E,39,30.2,58,32.8,46
2017-12-29,NSW,Wollongong,068228,19.4,25.8,0,,,SW,22,22.7,85,23.2,84
2017-12-29,VIC,Bendigo,081123,20.6,30.6,0.8,,,SW,39,23.6,76,29.6,47
2017-12-29,NSW,Newcastle,061055,20.8,26.3,0,,,ENE,41,24.2,78,25.7,68
2017-12-29,SA,Adelaide,023034,18.2,22.7,2.4,2.8,1.9,WSW,33,20.3,70,21.5,64
2017-12-29,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,18.9,28.9,0,,,NNE,39,22.5,81,27.8,48
2017-12-29,NT,Darwin,014015,26.1,33.7,0,5.2,7.4,S,31,30.8,68,32.4,66
2017-12-29,VIC,Ballarat,089002,15.6,26.6,0,,,NNW,44,21.4,83,18.9,99
2017-12-29,QLD,Townsville,032040,26.0,33.2,0,,,NE,35,30.8,55,31.5,49
2017-12-29,NSW,Canberra,070351,18.3,33.4,0,,,NW,46,24.7,56,31.3,33
2017-12-29,QLD,Cairns,031011,24.9,34.3,0,,,E,39,29.8,61,32.6,47
2017-12-29,WA,Perth,009021,15.6,30.0,0,8.8,13.1,WSW,41,22.9,43,27.5,38
2017-12-29,VIC,Melbourne,086338,18.6,24.4,0.2,5.8,1.0,SSW,35,19.5,78,20.0,85
2017-12-29,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,22.4,28.8,10.2,,,NNE,26,26.0,91,27.3,74
2017-12-29,NSW,Albury,072160,21.0,27.3,1.4,,,SSE,33,23.0,82,25.9,66
2017-12-29,VIC,Geelong,087184,17.2,22.6,0,,,SSW,26,19.3,79,18.7,93
2017-12-29,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,21.9,29.9,0,,,NE,26,27.5,65,28.5,62
2017-12-30,NSW,Wollongong,068228,21.6,29.7,0.6,,,SE,46,25.2,73,26.8,69
2017-12-30,QLD,Townsville,032040,25.8,33.6,0.2,,,N,35,30.2,60,31.7,49
2017-12-30,QLD,Brisbane,040913,23.3,32.2,0,8.6,7.8,NE,24,28.9,55,30.4,65
2017-12-30,VIC,Melbourne,086338,15.6,21.3,8.4,4.2,8.1,SSW,65,19.0,60,19.6,71
2017-12-30,VIC,Bendigo,081123,13.6,25.3,0.4,,,SW,43,17.8,60,22.2,47
2017-12-30,QLD,Cairns,031011,22.0,33.9,0,,,ENE,46,29.0,61,31.2,62
2017-12-30,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,21.0,31.3,0,,,NNE,43,29.0,54,28.1,72
2017-12-30,VIC,Geelong,087184,13.6,22.8,4.6,,,W,56,17.9,78,21.9,41
2017-12-30,NSW,Canberra,070351,18.6,28.3,16.4,,,WNW,50,22.8,70,27.8,33
2017-12-30,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,23.4,31.5,0,,,NW,41,27.2,61,28.0,74
2017-12-30,NSW,Albury,072160,20.3,27.7,13.8,,,W,44,23.0,65,26.2,36
2017-12-30,VIC,Ballarat,089002,8.2,18.6,1.4,,,WSW,50,14.7,81,16.6,70
2017-12-30,SA,Adelaide,023034,17.4,22.7,0.2,4.8,10.2,SW,41,19.1,72,22.0,51
2017-12-30,NT,Darwin,014015,24.2,34.8,1.2,4.4,11.2,NW,28,29.9,71,33.6,61
2017-12-30,NSW,Newcastle,061055,23.2,34.1,2.0,,,NW,52,24.6,81,31.2,50
2017-12-30,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,19.1,30.2,0,,,N,31,23.6,70,30.2,49
2017-12-31,QLD,Toowoomba,041529,21.1,30.2,1.4,,,E,54,24.7,75,23.6,66
2017-12-31,NSW,Canberra,070351,14.9,27.9,0,,,NNW,37,19.7,65,26.2,37
2017-12-31,VIC,Bendigo,081123,8.9,29.0,0,,,WNW,33,17.3,54,26.7,28
2017-12-31,NSW,Newcastle,061055,21.3,25.3,0.2,,,SSE,46,22.5,78,22.4,82
2017-12-31,NSW,Wollongong,068228,18.9,23.4,19.6,,,NNE,48,19.2,93,21.1,84
2017-12-31,QLD,Sunshine C,040861,24.1,32.5,0,,,SSW,65,30.3,62,27.1,78
2017-12-31,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,22.4,29.1,14.8,,,SE,56,27.1,84,25.6,97
2017-12-31,VIC,Geelong,087184,9.8,25.9,0,,,SSE,33,16.4,70,23.9,48
2017-12-31,QLD,Brisbane,040913,24.7,33.6,0,8.0,6.6,E,31,30.0,63,27.1,76
2017-12-31,VIC,Melbourne,086338,12.0,25.7,0.2,4.0,13.5,S,33,17.3,60,22.5,48
2017-12-31,WA,Perth,009021,19.7,33.6,0,12.4,13.2,WSW,41,26.0,45,30.6,36
2017-12-31,VIC,Ballarat,089002,5.7,25.2,2.0,,,W,39,12.8,77,23.5,35
2017-12-31,QLD,Townsville,032040,26.7,33.3,0,,,NNE,33,30.8,55,33.0,44
2017-12-31,NT,Darwin,014015,27.4,34.1,0,6.0,8.6,N,26,30.8,73,32.8,59
2017-12-31,QLD,Cairns,031011,21.6,33.1,0,,,NNE,28,29.9,61,31.2,54
2017-12-31,NSW,Albury,072160,12.7,29.5,0,,,WNW,33,19.9,67,27.7,30
2017-12-31,SA,Adelaide,023034,13.7,22.3,0,8.0,9.7,SW,35,17.7,59,21.4,53
```

What I have done is:

```
wind_direction = {}
expected_date = "2017-12-26"
is_first_line = True

for row in open("climate_data_Dec2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    date = values[0]
    wind = values[9]
    if date == expected_date:
      if wind in wind_direction:
         wind_direction[wind] += 1
      else:
         wind_direction[wind] = 1


for key in sorted(wind_direction):
  print(key, ":", wind_direction[key])
```

I think I am somewhat close but I am lacking the values with 0 in it.

My output is:

```
"E : 4
ENE : 2
ESE : 1
NE : 1
NNE : 1
NNW : 1
SE : 3
SSE : 3
SW : 1"
```

My question is, is my how do I get the remaining values to exist in the dictionary, and still ascribe it with 0.

The desired answer is:

```
E : 4
ENE : 2
ESE : 1
N : 0
NE : 1
NNE : 1
NNW : 1
NW : 0
S : 0
SE : 3
SSE : 3
SSW : 0
SW : 1
W : 0
WNW : 0
WSW : 0
```

Comment: Are you willing to use `pandas`? It would make this pretty fast and easy

Comment: @sacul Unforunately not, because I have not learnt that yet sorry

Comment: I am beginner level on python. Can only understand very smple language and syntax haha

Comment: Well, one *could* argue that `pandas` would make it much more simple... but if you want a pure python script, I'm sure someone will provide :)

Comment: @sacul can you take a look at my updated code in the question? do you know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I am an absolute beast.

```
wind_direction = {}
expected_date = "2017-12-26"
is_first_line = True

for row in open("climate_data_Dec2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    date = values[0]
    wind = values[9]
    if date == expected_date:
      if wind in wind_direction:
         wind_direction[wind] += 1
      else:
         wind_direction[wind] = 1
    if date not in wind_direction:
      if wind in wind_direction:
         wind_direction[wind] += 0
      else:
         wind_direction[wind] = 0

for key in sorted(wind_direction):
  print(key, ":", wind_direction[key])
```

Output would be:

```
E : 4
ENE : 2
ESE : 1
N : 0
NE : 1
NNE : 1
NNW : 1
NW : 0
S : 0
SE : 3
SSE : 3
SSW : 0
SW : 1
W : 0
WNW : 0
WSW : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if wind in wind_direction:
        if date == expected_date:
            wind_direction[wind] += 1
    else:
        if date == expected_date:
            wind_direction[wind] = 1
        else:
            wind_direction[wind] = 0
```

Comment: This will let you read also directions not featured in that date

Answer (score -1):

As also suggested by @sacul, pandas is probably best suited for this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("~/Desktop/datas.csv",header=0,sep=",")
df=df[df["Date"]=="2017-12-26"]

answ={}
winds=list(set(df[df.columns[9]]))
for i in winds:
    answ[i]=len(df[df[df.columns[9]]==str(i)])
print(answ)
```

Comment: The only values I am missing are: N : 0
NW : 0
S : 0
SSW : 0
W : 0
WNW : 0
WSW : 0

Comment: So I am missing all the values that are 0 because they don't exist for 26th of december, but somehow i need to accoutnf ro these missing values in my solution

Comment: Maybe I need to consider the whole data set of value[9]? but how

Comment: You need to iterate over the entire column 9 at least once to find all the possible wind directions. Since you are iterating over the rows that have the corresponding date this becomes unfeasible. @Rakesh answer solves your problem in this sense. However if you really insist you can put the if date == expected_date condition after the wind in wind_direction, so that you explore the entire dataset and get all the wind directions.